# Trim off the exceeding chars if length of variable exceeds 13 symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a file manager in PHP and JavaScript, and I am facing a situation where the file names are too long and exceed their html containers.

```
f.fName; // this will be the variable having the file name.
```

and the max length for file names is 13.

So my goal is to trim off the exceeding characters if the file name's length exceeds 13 symbols.

```
var maxLength = "tabcontrol.ht";
var temp = undefined;
if (f.fName.length <= maxLength.length) {
    temp = f.fName;
} else {
    temp = f.fName.substring(0, f.fName.length - maxLength.length);
}
```

I have no clue of what I am doing so can anyone explain in brief of how to achieve this?

Comment: @Regent That sure was helpful of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
var s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var trimmed = s.substring(0,Math.min(13,s.length));
```

trimmed would have max 13 characters of string s.

Hope it helped

Comment: So that if the length of the string is less than 13, you would get the whole string. @KBN